# How can I test my Sustainsys SAML 2 implementation is using certificates

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have a .cer file for each of my IDPs and I have a .pfx for my service. All seems to work fine but if I comment out the lines that adds the certificates to the signing keys (either the IDP or SP certificates) it still works. Looks like they are not being used to me... What test can I do to ensure we are using the certificates to validate responses?

UPDATE: So I have two IDPs configured. The sustainsys stub and Azure AD. Both work well but if I remove the sustainsys certificate all still works fine. If I remove the Azure AD certificate it stops working. How do I control this behaviour?

UPDATE: After checking Katana logs its clear that the Azure AD integration does not work when you do not assign the Azure AD certificate. But why does the sustainsys stub still work?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out you cannot control the behaviour - the Sustainsys library will automatically handle signature validation. The reason why the Sustainsys IDP would work when I commented out where I add the certificate is because I set the federation url which enabled the Sustainsys library to go and fetch the certificate automatically. Once I commented the federation url out, the SAML integration to the Sustainsys stub stopped working. Once it stopped working I assigned the wrong certificate to make sure it would still fail. Then after that I assigned the correct certificate and can see all is working only with the correct certificate.